# Grid View button height and weight not fixed

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/numerickeypad"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumtwo"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/two" />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumthree"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/three" />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumfour"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/four" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumfive"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/five" />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumsix"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/six" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumseven"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/seven" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumeight"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/eight" />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumnine"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/nine" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumzero"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="@string/zero" />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumclear"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogbox_buttonnumone"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedtext"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:width="80dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

this is my gridlayout view it works perfect on my screen but when i change orientation its not really good is there a way to set height and weight of button in grid view to other size not a fixed size so when there is a change in screen it will adjust

Comment: Make a separate layout for the landscape and set height and width in that layout accordingly.

Comment: is there a way to set height and weight to like weight?and not a specific 50 dp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can put LinearLayout inside the GridLayout and then put all
>   buttons inside that LinearLayout and easily can set the weight of
>   buttons.

Comment: sorry to busy doing my project wasnt able to check on this again.

Comment: @HakHak that's ok. but main thing i want to know, your problem was solved or not by this way.

Comment: actually i made it as simple as making only a linear layout i got the idea from your answer thats why i accepted it as a helpful answer your answer gave me idea..and i appreciate it so much happy coding mate :)